# BootstrapVue - Number Form Input not working in Firefox

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-component

Using BootstrapVue, I have the following input element inside a `b-form`:

```
<b-form-input v-model="myTest" type="number" max="9999"></b-form-input>
```

I want the following behavior:

1. The user should be allowed to only enter digits (and not letters or other characters). I tried implementing this with `type="number"`, but it is only having an effect in Chrome, and not Firefox.
2. The maximum number that the user can enter should be four digits. I tried implementing this with `max="9999"`, but it doesn't have any effect.

How do I implement this intended behavior?

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in boostrap-vue from the documentation. You can do it with vanilla js though:

```html
<b-form-input id="range-1" v-model="value" type="number" onkeyup="parseNum(this)"></b-form-input>
```

```js
let parseNum = function(scope){ //scope is 'this' which is html input element
  if(parseInt(scope.value)>999) scope.value =9999 // check if too large
  if(isNaN(parseInt(scope.value))) scope.value=1 // check if number
}
```

See this in action below:

```js
let parseNum = function(scope){
  if(parseInt(scope.value)>999) scope.value =9999 
  if(isNaN(parseInt(scope.value))) scope.value=1 
}

const app = new Vue({
    data() {
      return {
        value: '2'
      }
    },
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <label for="range-1">Example range with min and max</label>
    <b-form-input id="range-1" v-model="value" type="number" onkeyup="parseNum(this)"></b-form-input>
    <div class="mt-2">Value: {{ value }}</div>
 </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tehsurfer/xp1r6zq7/7/)